# MySQL query to find Instructor with min pay along with course

Tags: mysql

I have a table called instructor with `ID, prof_id, course and pay` attributes. I want to query each professor with the minimum pay per course along with the course.

This is what I have but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT prof_id, course, min(pay) as min_pay 
FROM instructor
GROUP BY prof_id;
```

the above query returns each `prof_id` with the min `pay` but the entire `course` column have the same course name (whichever course  is on the first row)

I also tried grouping by prof_id and course but it doesn't seem to do work either. My guess is the issue is in the group by.

[image]

Note: I am new to DB. So if this is a stupid question to ask I apologize in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE instructor(
id int,
prof_id int, 
course varchar(20),  
pay int
                      );

INSERT INTO  instructor VALUES 
(1,1,'MATH',2000),
(2,1,'ECON',2300),
(3,1,'BIO',1800),
(4,2,'PHY',3000),
(5,2,'CHEM',4300),
(6,3,'SOCI',3400),
(7,3,'PYSC',2100),
(8,3,'MUSIC',1300);


SELECT prof_id, course, pay 
FROM instructor
WHERE (prof_id,pay) in ( select prof_id, 
                                min(pay) 
                         FROM instructor 
                         group by prof_id
                        );
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> prof_id   course  pay
> 1 BIO     1800
> 2 PHY     3000
> 3 MUSIC   1300
> ```
>
> Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/184